# Plotly Dash, No module named 'dash_extensions.websockets'

Tags: python, websocket, plotly-dash

I have a problem with running my Dash application.

**Error:**

```
from dash_extensions.websockets import run_server
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_extensions.websockets'
```

**Additional info:**

- six months earlier such a problem wasn't presented (last code modification was 30 March and all worked!)
- but now after some pause I tried to run the application and got error about `dash_extensions` (no code modifications are made, but linux distro is changed from LinuxMint to UbuntuCinnamon, and thus miniconda freshely installed)

I am using `conda`. The package `dash_extensions` is installed and presented in the `site-packages` folder, **but error is raised**.

For information, I have package requirements described in the file:

```
name: vital_dash
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - conda-build
  - python
  - pandas
  - autopep8
  - icecream
  - flask-socketio
  - gevent
  - gevent-websocket
  - websocket-client
  - dash
  - dash-core-components
  - dash-html-components
  - dash-bootstrap-components
  - dash-daq
  - pip
  - pip:
    - Flask-Sockets
    - dash-extensions
    - circular-buffer-numpy
```

I have tried change **python** version, which I used earlier, but no positive results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing via Conda instead of pip? Looks like more support has been added since March.

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash-extensions
```